# Can i save comment info in my Jar file(generated by Ant)?

Tags: eclipse, ant, javadoc, comments

When I build my project to a Jar file with Ant, I generate javadoc the same time.

#### But when I use this Jar in a new Project, I can't see the Jar's comment in the Eclipse(pressing F2).

So I tried to add the javadoc files' location path in 'javadoc Location' of Properties of my new Project,it doesn't work, even if Eclipse tell me the 'Location is likely valid'.

When I open it in Browser,the Url is like `file:///file:/C:/Users/topxebec/Desktop/doc/index.html`, there's two prefix in the url,but in the eclipse I only have `file:/C:/Users/topxebec/Desktop/doc/index.html,`.

I tried to change it to `C:/Users/tongxuebin/Desktop/doc/` but Eclipse said it was a Invalid URL.

So how to solve this problem?  Or,can I simply save the comments in the Jar when it generated by Ant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that you can't put the javadoc in the same jar as the class files, so that eclipse will automatically show the doc.

A solution is to include the source-code. This will also help, if you need to debug the classes in that jar.

This answer: [How can I build my jar file so that users who use the library will be able to see the javadoc in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497009/how-can-i-build-my-jar-file-so-that-users-who-use-the-library-will-be-able-to-se) covers that case. But it just boils down to:

```
<target name="jar.noCompile.src">  
    <jar destfile="${ant.project.name}.jar">  
      <fileset dir="${classes}"/>  
      <fileset dir="${src}" includes="**/*.java"/>  
    </jar>  
</target>
```

Comment: Thank you,I followed your suggestion and I got a javadoc embedded Jar file,but the question now is:After I add this Jar as external jars to my classpath,I also can't see comments in my eclipse(by pressing F2), must I unpack the javadoc from my Jar and then attach the doc to my Jar manual?

Comment: What I want is to make users who use my Jar can see the COMMENTS of the method or field WITH OUT need to attach Javadoc or Source file manually. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: @topxebec hm... I think I was wrong, it seems that you can't put the javadoc in that jar, eclipse does need it somewhere outside (can't find anything specific on that). What definitly works is including the src files, this will show the javadoc comments(but you will have the src files in the jar)